# replace all lines starting with

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace all lines in multiline string starting with `#`

```
str.replace(/^#([^\n]*)\n$/gm, '<h1>$1</h1>')
```

## multiline string

```
# headline
some text

# new headline
some more text
```

## result string

```
<h1>headline</h1>
some text

<h1>new headline</h1>
some more text
```

Comment: So the goal is to match everything from any start-of-line + hash to the closest end-of-line? Why does that feel trivial to me?

Answer (score 8):

try this regexp `/^#(.*)$/mg` like this

```
str.replace(/^#(.*)$/mg,"<h1>$1</h1")
```

Comment: nice, was not aware multiline flag made `^` and `$` anchor to line ends

Comment: in the replacement pattern `$1` must not be handled like a variable but is a part of the string `'<b>$1</b>'` :) else it would not work

Answer (score 1):

If your line breaks are `\n`, then this will work:

```
#(.*?)(\n|$)
```

**Javascript:**

```
str.replace(/#(.*?)(\n|$)/g,"<h1>$1</h1>")
```

Answer (score 0):

`^#\s(\w+)$` Will match any line beginning with a #, followed by a single whitespace character and then followed by at least 1 word character (A-Z, 0-9 and underscores). It then stores a match group of the headline text.

You should be able to call this match group with \1.